# Subtitles don't appear using Google Cast v3 SDK

Tags: ios, swift, chromecast, google-cast

I'm upgrading our iOS sender SDK from v2 to v3 and running into problems getting subtitles to appear. I see all the different languages appearing in the Expanded Controller subtitle list, but when I select one, nothing seems to happen.

The code is pretty abstracted across a bunch of VCs but here's the gist of it:

```
extension GCKMediaInformation {

...

    public class func mediaInformationForLocalMedia(_ media: Media, tracks: [GCKMediaTrack]) -> GCKMediaInformation {
        if tracks.count > 0 {
            let textTrackStyle = GCKMediaTextTrackStyle.createDefault()
            textTrackStyle.foregroundColor = GCKColor(cssString: "#FF000080")
            textTrackStyle.fontFamily = "serif"
            return GCKMediaInformation(contentID: media.streamURL!, streamType: .buffered, contentType: media.mimeType, metadata: metaData, streamDuration: 0, mediaTracks: tracks, textTrackStyle: GCKMediaTextTrackStyle.createDefault(), customData: nil)
        } else {
            return GCKMediaInformation(contentID: media.streamURL!, streamType: .buffered, contentType: media.mimeType, metadata: metaData, streamDuration: 0, customData: nil)

        }   
    }
}

open func playMediaNow(_ media: GCKMediaInformation, subtitle: VideoSubtitles?, tracks: [GCKMediaTrack]) {
    let session = GCKCastContext.sharedInstance().sessionManager.currentCastSession
    if (session != nil) {
        let trackIds = tracks.map { $0.identifier }
        session?.remoteMediaClient?.loadMedia(media, autoplay: true, playPosition: resumeTime, activeTrackIDs: trackIds as [NSNumber]!)
    }
}

func makeSubtitleTracks(_ subtitles: [VideoSubtitles]) -> [GCKMediaTrack] {
    var tracks = [GCKMediaTrack]()
    for subIndex in 0...(subtitles.count-1) {
        let sub = subtitles[subIndex]
        let subTrack = GCKMediaTrack(identifier: subIndex, contentIdentifier: sub.url!, contentType: "text/vtt", type: GCKMediaTrackType.text, textSubtype: GCKMediaTextTrackSubtype.subtitles, name: sub.language!, languageCode: sub.code!, customData: nil)
        tracks.append(subTrack)
    }
    return tracks
}



fileprivate func loadVideoPlayer() {

    let session = GCKCastContext.sharedInstance().sessionManager.currentCastSession
    if (session != nil) {
        APIManager.sharedInstance.getVideoStream(videoGUID) { [unowned self] (result: Result<VideoStream>) in
            guard let stream_url = result.value?.stream_url else { return }                
            APIManager.sharedInstance.getVideoSubtitles(self.videoGUID, subFormat: "webvtt", completionHandler: { (result: Result<[VideoSubtitles]>) -> Void in
                guard let subtitles = result.value else { return }
                let subtitle = subtitles.filter{ $0.code == "en" }.first
                let tracks = self.makeSubtitleTracks(subtitles)
                let media = Media(contentId: self.videoGUID, streamURL: stream_url, resumeTime: self.resumeTime, streamType: .buffered, duration: self.duration, videoDataSource: self.dataSource)
                let gckMedia = GCKMediaInformation.mediaInformationForLocalMedia(media, tracks: tracks)
                CastDeviceController.sharedInstance.playMediaNow(gckMedia, subtitle: subtitle, tracks: tracks)

            })
        }
}
```

I've confirmed that the subtitle.url vtt links are correct but still no dice. Everything else seems to be working pretty well.

Comment: Does the CastVideos-ios app, from GitHub, exhibits the same issue?

Comment: Sorry I didn't see your reply until now somehow. So a couple things: we use 100% Swift 3.0 (and it would be nice if you all could get a Swift example repo up at some point) so I haven't directly tried the Obj-C example with our assets. It would be a lot of extra work just to test out whether the sample works. What I do know is that our videos work fine with the 2.x SDK code we've had in place for about a year now.

I'm wondering though — I'm waiting on a new 3.0 receiver. Is it possible the 3.0 iOS sender SDK is not totally compatible with a 2.x receiver?

Comment: I am not aware of any "incompatibility" issue. What I was suggesting was to grab the CastVideos-ios from our GitHub and just update the link to a vtt file to point to yours to see if it works or not; that should be pretty straightforward to test.

Comment: So the answer is that this ended up working fine on the 3.0 receiver I got. And the problem was I guess that segmented webvtts weren't really supported when we made the 2.0 receiver, so we were doing some custom hackery in custom channels that I wasn't really aware of when I started this project. I was able to get our subs working with the v3.0 sender on both the 2.0 and 3.0 receivers though.